# How to destroy a built object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I delete or destroy an object located in memory, but not in the database?

```
irb(main):034:0> mentor.registered_students.build(:user_id => 20)
=> #<RegisteredStudent id: nil, user_id: 20, assigned_mentor_id: 1, description: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>

irb(main):035:0> mentor.registered_students.last
=> #<RegisteredStudent id: nil, user_id: 20, assigned_mentor_id: 1, description: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>

irb(main):036:0> mentor.registered_students.last.destroy
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
   (0.2ms)  COMMIT
=> #<RegisteredStudent id: nil, user_id: 20, assigned_mentor_id: 1, description: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>

irb(main):037:0> mentor.registered_students.last.delete
=> #<RegisteredStudent id: nil, user_id: 20, assigned_mentor_id: 1, description: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>

irb(main):038:0> mentor.registered_students.last
=> #<RegisteredStudent id: nil, user_id: 20, assigned_mentor_id: 1, description: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

I already used destroy or delete but they look for records in database.

CONTROLER ACTION:

```
  def mix
    unless params[:mentor_id].nil? || params[:students_id].nil?
      @mentor   = AssignedMentor.find params[:mentor_id]
      @students = params[:students_id]
      @students.each do |student|
        if student[1] == "0"
          registered_student = RegisteredStudent.where("assigned_mentor_id = ? AND user_id = ?", @mentor.id, student[0] ).first
          registered_student.destroy
        end
        if student[1] == "1"
          @mentor.registered_students.build(:user_id => student[0])
          @mentor.save
          if @mentor.errors.size > 0
            @mentor.registered_students.reload
          end
        end
      end
      #redirect_to bind_admin_users_path
    end
    #flash[:alert] = t("labels.no_students")
    redirect_to bind_admin_users_path
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mentor.registered_students.reload
```

does the trick

Comment: That works but really doesnt delete the last object and loads the database

Comment: @drakedalfa I don't see any alternative. In which context do you plan to use this? If it is only in the console, then it's what `reload` is made for

Comment: its for an app web not in console

Comment: this code is in an each block checks some params if 0 or 1 create or delete the object.

Comment: @drakedalfa Interesting. Can you update your question with the code please?

Comment: @drakedalfa your code has larger issues: `@mentor.save` won't add a new student to the mentor existing registered students. You have to save the relationship (`@mentor.registered_students.build(:user_id => student[0])`) and not only `build` it.

Comment: mentor saves the relation but if an error appears the object is not created its just builded and because of the loop each i need clear the build, until now the .reload works but is not a solution.